# GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0) returns 1280

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm testing my android app on few devices. It works great on Samsung Galaxy Note3 but shows nothing on HTC One X.

`GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0)` returns 1280

AFAIK at least 2 textures should be supported by OpenGL implementation, so why it fails and how can i walk-around it?

Full binding code:

```
/**
 * Load the texture for the square.
 *
 */
public void setGLTexture(Bitmap bitmap) {
    GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    activeTextureIndex = (activeTextureIndex + 1) % TEXTURES_COUNT;

    Log.d("OPENGL_TEXTURE", "setting new bitmap " + bitmap + " for " + activeTextureIndex );

    GLES20.glActiveTexture(textureIds[activeTextureIndex]);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextures[activeTextureIndex]);

    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);

    GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}

/** The texture pointer. */
private int activeTextureIndex = -1; // will be incremented before usage
private static final int TEXTURES_COUNT = 2;

private static final int[] textureIds = new int[] {
    GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0,
    GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1,
    GLES20.GL_TEXTURE2,
    GLES20.GL_TEXTURE3,
    GLES20.GL_TEXTURE4,
    GLES20.GL_TEXTURE5,
    GLES20.GL_TEXTURE6,
    GLES20.GL_TEXTURE7,
    GLES20.GL_TEXTURE8,
    GLES20.GL_TEXTURE9,
    GLES20.GL_TEXTURE10
};
```

Comment: I misread your code before. It's confusing that your array of texture units is called `textureIds`, when you have a separate array of actual texture IDs (`mTextures`). Can you provide info on how you are populating `mTextures`? I don't really understand what you're doing binding a texture to a new texture unit every time you call this.

Comment: `GLES20.glGenTextures(TEXTURES_COUNT, mTextures, 0);`

Comment: Kind of weird, but maybe it's throwing that error because you are calling it after disabling texturing? Why are you doing that, anyway?